# Strange listings, minipage and newcommand interaction

Tags: macros, listings, minipage

I like to define the following command :

```
\newcommand{\page}[2]{\begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth} #2 \end{minipage}}
```

So that I can do stuff like

```
\page{0.1}{blabla}\page{0.3}{lalala}
```

I've recently discovered the package `listings` and I've noticed a very strange interaction.

This code doesn't trigger any error :

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}  
    bla bla
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

But this :

```
\page{0.5}{
\begin{lstlisting}  
    bla bla
\end{lstlisting}
}
```

throws : `Emergency stop. [...] job aborted, no legal \end found`

And I must say I'm very confused, since I do not see much difference between those two.

Comment: You cannot use the `lstlisting` environment in the argument to another command. I don't think you gain so much with `\page` rather than the full environment form.

Comment: @egreg Oh well that explains it! You just can't ? Isn't there any way to do so ?

Comment: @egreg about `\page`, I use *a lot* of minipages in my documents for formating, and I can assure you that the gain of time is huge.

Comment: you can not use any verbatim (or verbatim-like command) inside the argument of another command, but more generally hiding environment syntax has several disadvantages, making it harder for editors to give correct syntax highlighting and context sensitive help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, thank you. I didn't know that was a bad habit, I actually do that for pretty much any environment - `enumerate`, `minipage` with `fbox`... I'm sorry for editors but this makes writing so much more comfortable!

Comment: @krirkrirk do you use a tex-specific editing environment? in most adding things like `\begin{enumerate} \end{enumerate}` can be done in two or three keystrokes so defining a `\foo{...}`  doesn't mean less typing, and obscures the source document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use Texmaker. I do not use those newcommands just for something like `\begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate}`. Most of the times I use them so that I don't have to specify options. E.G : for something like`\begin{enumerate}[$\bullet$] ... \end{enumerate}`, I only type `\bul{...}`. Similarly, `\fpage{...}` gives me `\fbox{\begin{minipage} ... \end{minipage}}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This felt like something smart when I decided to define those newcommands, but yeah it's highly likely that I'm missing even easier way of doing that. I suspect there a bunch of Texmaker keyboard shortcuts that I should learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you define our `\page` macro using directly primitive commands (`\vtop` or `\vbox`), then you will not have problem with verbatim environment inside `\page` parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\page#1{\vtop\bgroup \hsize=#1\hsize \let\next}

\begin{document}

\page{0.5}{
\begin{verbatim}
bla bla
\end{verbatim}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's `\def\page#1{\vtop\bgroup \hsize=#1\hsize \let\next}
` doing, but it indeed allows a `lstlisting` argument. Yet, it does not seem to behave like `minipage`. In particular, each page is printed on a new line, while pages from `minipage` can be put on a same line, which is perfect for layout.

Comment: @krirkrirk You can insert `\leavevmode` just before `\vtop`, it means `\def\page#1{\leavevmode\vtop\bgroup...`. Then each `\page` behaves as one "big" character, i. e. it starts horizontal mode (like minipage).